# Python- mean every n values of a coulmn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, average, mean

There are just a few months I started I python. So, working on big CSV files(example 479 rows x 23 columns or bigger), I want to calculate the mean of a specific column every n values. For example, if n=5, mean must be calculated for 0-5, 5-10, 10-15 etc (not like rolling).

A sample of data in the photo and the column of interest is for example "Speed" or any other.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59eBV.png)

I tried to loop over the CSV or isolating the column I want into an array and tried xrange but it really not working so good.

Αny idea would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: provide sample data in text and expected output

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` is your frend:

```
numrows=5

groups = np.arange(len(df))//numrows
df['your_column'].groupby(groups).mean()
```

Comment: Don't you have to convert groups into a df column in order to reference it in the groupby parenthesis, or is np.arrange referencing the index directly somehow?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have an index starting at 0 (which you would normally) you can do the following:

```
df.groupby(df.index // 5)['colname'].mean()
```